# A question based on Interior , Closure of sets

Tags: real-analysis

This particular question is part of my real analysis assignment which couldnot be discussed .

Edit: In all four options It would be distinct instead of disjoint. Sorry for typo!!

> For a set A which is proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$ , denote by Cl(A) the closure of A , and by Int(A) the interior of A . There is a set A ( proper subset of $\mathbb{R}$) such that

1. A, cl(A) and Int(A) are pairwise distinct.
2. A, cl(A) and Int(A)  and Cl(Int(A)) are pairwise distinct.
3. A, cl(A) and Int(A) and Int(Cl(A)) are pairwise distinct.
4. A, cl(A) and Int(A), Cl(Int(A)), Int(Cl(A)) are pairwise distinct.

For 1. taking $\mathbb{Q}$ was sufficient . But along with this example , I tried some more examples which could not satisfy 2.,3.,4. .

While checking answers I got 2.,3.4. false ie they can never be satisfied .

Can anyone please tell what is reasoning behind it

Comment: Taking $A = \emptyset$ will satisfy all four properties.

Comment: Are you sure that you meant to write “pairwise disjoint”? After all, unless $A=\emptyset$, $A$ and $\operatorname{Cl}(A)$ never are disjoint.

Comment: $Int(A) \subset A$ and so it's easy to show (but it's not a given and must be shown) that $cl(Int(A)) \subset cl(A)$.  Likewise $Int(Cl(A)) \subset Cl(A)$ and as $A\subset Cl(A)$ then $\int(A) \subset \int(Cl(A))$ and so on.

Comment: We do always have $Int(A) \subset A \subset Cl(A)$ don't we? And the only way for $B,C$ with $B \subset C$ disjoint is if $B$ is empty, right?  So $A=\emptyset$ will satisfy all but is the only one that will satisfy all.  I think the problem as presented is flawed.  But it can and should be salvaged as an excercise that would greatly improve intuition.

Comment: Argh..  those integerall signs $\int$ in my comment above where the result of by habit putting a slash "\" before "int".  So instead of being \$int\$ which would render as $int$ it was \$\int\$ which renders as $\int$.  .... Oops.

Comment: @fleablood `\operatorname{int}` to the rescue.

Comment: pairwise disjoint **should** read pairwise *distinct*. Quite an essential difference.

Comment: "\operatorname{int} to the rescue." not for a bloody comment it won't.  I didn't type "\int" because I wanted to format it!  I typed "int" because it was a typo that out of force of habit I type "\" before things that don't need them (such as variable names and numbers and in this case the letters I N T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Kuratowski's $14$-set theorem (e.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem))
where you can also find the example

$$A = (0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \{3\} \cup ([4,5]\cap \Bbb Q)$$

as a set that works for all your questions (of course "disjoint" you wrote is nonsense, and should be "distinct").